# moq and fetching an exception

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, moq

I'm trying to learn moq test with some simple examples
I have

```
public class CustomerService
{
   private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository;
   public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository repository)
   {
       _repository = repository;
   }

   public void CreateWithMoney(CustomerDTO dto)
   {                  
        var cust = new Customer { FirstName = dto.FirstName, LastName = dto.LastName, FinacialStatus = dto.FinacialStatus };
        if (cust.FinacialStatus < 500)
        {
            throw new NotEnoughMoneyException();                
        }
        _repository.Save(cust);
    }
}



[Test]
public void ThrowExceptionIfMoneyIsLessThan500()
{
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();        
    var mockService = new Mock<CustomerService>(mockRepo.Object);

    mockService.Setup(x => x.CreateWithMoney(It.IsAny<CustomerDTO>()))
                 .Throws<NotImplementedException>();  

}
```

I dont knwo how to verify that is true and most importantly I cannot run test,

> cause  I'm getting this error Expected:
>   EntityTest.TDD.NotEnoughMoneyException But was:
>   System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual
>   (overridable in VB) member: x =>
>   x.CreateWithMoney(It.IsAny())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mock the `CreateWithMoney` method because it is not virtual. Add the `virtual` keyword to it:

```
public virtual void CreateWithMoney(CustomerDTO dto)
{
  ...
}
```

There is a better solution for your unit test if you want to test that an exception is thrown when money is less than 500:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(NotEnoughMoneyException))]
public void ThrowExceptionIfMoneyIsLessThan500()
{
  var repository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>().Object;
  var dto = ...; // Instantiate CustomerDTO that returns a value > 500 for FinancialStatus property

  var target = new CustomerService(repository);

  target.CreateWithMoney(dto);
}
```

As you can see there is the `ExpectedException` attribute that specifies the type of exception you are expecting. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) for more information.

Comment: so, to conclude, I do not need to add verify assert at the end of test if I use  expectedexception as atrribute

Comment: Right, MSTest is handling the exception here. You only specify the exception you except when the test is run.

Comment: This all depends on which testing framework you use. However many of them have an attribute like this, for example [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx), and [`NUnit.Framework.ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.4.8), and [`csUnit.ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](http://www.csunit.org/documentation/classdoc.1.8/csUnit.ExpectedExceptionAttribute.html), and so on.